# Header in Listview using BaseAdapter

Tags: android

How do you put header in a ListView using BaseAdapter? Or is there any other way beside the one I'm using below.

I've tried using the function `addHeaderView(header)` but still no luck.

Need some help. Thanks! The code is below.

```
public class ViewInterview extends Activity {

InterviewList interviewList = null;
TextView header;
ListView list = null;

static ArrayList<String> titlelist;
static ArrayList<String> markingslist;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_interview);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_interview);
    String TAG = "INTERVIEW LIST";
    header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header);
    header.setText("Test");

    titlelist = new ArrayList<String>();
    markingslist = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xreader = parser.getXMLReader();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.booklist));

        InterviewHandler myInterviewHandler = new InterviewHandler();
        xreader.setContentHandler(myInterviewHandler);
        xreader.parse(new InputSource(is.getByteStream()));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "InterviewList parse exception " + e.getMessage());
    }

    //---get result from InterviewHandler tempInterviewList
    interviewList = InterviewHandler.tempInterviewList;
    String strMarkings = interviewList.getMarkings().get(0);
    String[] arrMarkings = strMarkings.split("\\|\\|");
    for(int i=0; i<arrMarkings.length; i++) {
        titlelist.add("Title " + interviewList.getTitle().get(0));
        markingslist.add(arrMarkings[i]);
    }
    //list.addHeaderView(header);
    //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, interviewList.interview));

    list.setAdapter(new InterviewAdapter(this,titlelist,markingslist));

}

public static class InterviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<String> dataTitle;
    private List<String> dataMarkings;

    public InterviewAdapter(Context context, List<String> dataTitle, List<String> dataMarkings) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        dataTitle = this.dataTitle;
        dataMarkings = this.dataMarkings;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return titlelist.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_interview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.markings = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.markings);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.title.setText(titlelist.get(position));
        holder.markings.setText(markingslist.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView markings;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**you simply cannot do**

```
View header = findViewById(R.layout.headerView);
lst.addHeaderView(header);
```

this will `NOT work` because the view which is being passed in `has to be inflated`. In a nutshell **when you do setContentView at the beginning of your activity the android framework automatically inflates the view and puts it to use. In order to inflate your header view**, all you have to do is

```
View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.headerView,null);
ls.addHeaderView(header);
```

lastly, add your adapter after you’ve set the header view and run the application. You should see your header view with the content you put into your adapter.

In my case, this works

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null); 

ListView listView = getListView();  
listView.addHeaderView(header);  

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,android.R.id.text1, names));
```

Comment: Good, but I'm using baseadapter. And I don't know where to put that code.

Comment: Adapter is different thing, Headerview it concern only to listview,,,

Comment: Oh I see. Things already worked out. I've edited all my XML Layouts. Thanks!

Comment: Yup. Based on what you answered and some blog.

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar problem some time ago and this is the solution I came up with...

I created a view I like to call `SandwichListView` that looks something like this:

```
public class SandwichListView extends ListView {

private View header = null;
private View footer = null;

/* here you have to publicly override the constructors */

@Override
public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    if (header == null) {
        addHeaderView(child);
        header = child;
        return;
    } else if (footer == null) {
        addFooterView(child);
        footer = child;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Only a header and a footer allowed in this view, use Layouts");
    }
}

public View getHeader() {
    return header;
}

public View getFooter() {
    return footer;
}

}
```

The on your xml interface template you can use it like this:

```
<com.oos.kryten.views.SandwichListView
    android:id="@+id/sandwich"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/header"
            layout="@layout/details_header" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/footer" />
</com.oos.kryten.views.SandwichListView>
```

This way you can easily add a header and a footer in your xml and then use your Adapter as normal :)

PS: I think you can use the `<include />` directly, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this source code

```
View headerView = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, null, false);
list.addHeaderView(headerView );
```

> This will work. But the header will appear only if after setAdapter is
>   called.

Comment: Is it possible to make the header appear before `setAdapter` ?